# c++ array of an object resets, after it gets changed in a method

Tags: c++, arrays, class, reset

im new to c++, i learned java at the university. I was trying to start with a small beginner project. A console rpg. i made a GameEntity class, a player class that inherits the GameEntity class and some enums: GameType, Stats

```
int main(){

    GameEntity *opponent = new GameEntity("enemy", 20, 3, 4);
    Player *player = new Player("player", 40, 4, 4);

    //initialize combatStats
    player->prepareForCombat();
    opponent->prepareForCombat();

    int r = 0;
    while(!player->isDead() && !opponent->isDead()){
        player->chooseMove(*opponent, r);
        opponent->chooseMove(*player, r);
        r++;
    }
    if(!player->isDead()){
        cout << "you won!";
    }else{
        cout << "you lost!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**My Problem:**
i have an array for all the Stats, including hp.
`int combatStats[7];`
and a method to decrease the hp in GameEntity:

```
void decreaseHp(int damage)
    {
        if(damage <= 0)return;
        combatStats[Hp] = combatStats[Hp] - damage;
        cout << name << ": gets "<< damage << " damage." << '\n';
        cout << name << ": current health: " << getHp() << '\n';
        if(combatStats[Hp] <= 0){
            die();
        }
    }
```

the method changes the hp to its correct value and prints it out, but it changes back to its initial state, after the method stops.

i expected that an array doesn't, resets its value itself.

it had a private access modifyer, so i tried changing it to public, it did nothing.

here is the whole code:

```
//#include "GameEntity.cpp";
//#include "Player.cpp";
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

enum Stats{
    Hp = 0,Mind = 1,Str = 2,Dex = 3,End = 4,Int = 5,Wis = 6
};
enum GameType{
    thrust,slash,bludgeon,light,dark,heat,cold, mind, arcane
};

class GameEntity{
    protected:
        int baseStats[7];
        string name;
        bool isAllive = true;
        int blockVal = 0;
        
    public:
        GameEntity(string name, int hp, int pVal, int mVal){
            this->name = name;
            baseStats[Hp] = hp;
            baseStats[Mind] = 100;
            baseStats[Str] = pVal;
            baseStats[Dex] = pVal;
            baseStats[End] = hp/10;
            baseStats[Int] = mVal;
            baseStats[Wis] = mVal;
        }
        int combatStats[7];
        string getName(){return name;}
        int getHp(){return combatStats[Hp];}
        int getDex(){return combatStats[Dex];}
        int getInt(){return combatStats[Int];}
        int getEnd(){return combatStats[End];}
        int getStr(){return combatStats[Str];}
        int getWis(){return combatStats[Wis];}
        int getMind(){return combatStats[Mind];}
        void incrementDex(int i){combatStats[Dex] += i;}
        void incrementInt(int i){combatStats[Int]+= i;}
        void incrementEnd(int i){combatStats[End]+= i;}
        void incrementStr(int i){combatStats[Str]+= i;}
        void incrementWis(int i){combatStats[Wis]+= i;}
        void decrementDex(int d){combatStats[Dex]-= d;}
        void decrementInt(int d){combatStats[Int]-= d;}
        void decrementEnd(int d){combatStats[End]-= d;}
        void decrementStr(int d){combatStats[Str]-= d;}
        void decrementWis(int d){combatStats[Wis]-= d;}

    void chooseMove(GameEntity target, int round){
        cout << name << " health: " << combatStats[Hp] << '\n';
        blockVal = 0;
        if(round%2 == 0){
            cout << name << ": does a slash attack." << '\n';
            target.damage(10 , GameType::slash);
        }
        else if(round == 5 || round == 12){
            heal(5, GameType::light);
        }
        else{
            block(8);
        }
    }
    void damage(int damage, GameType type){
        if(blockVal > damage){
            blockVal -= damage;
            cout << name << ": blocked "<< damage << " damage." << '\n';
            damage = 0;
        }else if(blockVal < damage){
            damage -= blockVal;
            cout << name << ": blocked "<< blockVal << " damage." << '\n';
            blockVal = 0;
        }else{
            cout << name << ": blocked all damage. ("<< blockVal << ")" << '\n';
            damage = 0;
            blockVal = damage;
        }

        switch(type){
            case GameType::arcane: 
                decreaseHp(damage);
                break;
            default:
                cout << name << ": endured "<< combatStats[End] << " damage." << '\n';
                decreaseHp(damage-combatStats[End]);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    void heal(int healing, GameType type){
        if(type == GameType::light){
            combatStats[Hp] += healing;
            cout << name << ": healed by "<< healing << '\n';
        }
        if(combatStats[Hp] > baseStats[Hp]){
            combatStats[Hp] = baseStats[Hp];
        }
    }
    void block(int block){
        blockVal = block;
        cout << name << ": prepares to block." << '\n';
    }

    bool isDead(){
        return !isAllive;
    }

    void prepareForCombat(){
        combatStats[Hp] = baseStats[Hp];
        combatStats[Mind] = baseStats[Mind];
        combatStats[Str] = baseStats[Str];
        combatStats[Dex] = baseStats[Dex];
        combatStats[End] = baseStats[End];
        combatStats[Int] = baseStats[Int];
        combatStats[Wis] = baseStats[Wis];
    }
    
    void decreaseHp(int damage)
    {
        if(damage <= 0)return;
        combatStats[Hp] = combatStats[Hp] - damage;
        cout << name << ": gets "<< damage << " damage." << '\n';
        cout << name << ": current health: " << getHp() << '\n';
        if(combatStats[Hp] <= 0){
            die();
        }
    }

    void die(){
        cout << name << ": died" << '\n';
        isAllive = false;
    }
};
class Player : public GameEntity
{
    public:
        using GameEntity::GameEntity;
        //using GameEntity::isDead;
        void chooseMove(GameEntity target, int round){
            cout << name << " health: " << combatStats[Hp] << '\n';
            blockVal = 0;
            cout <<"System: what do you want to do?" << '\n';
            cout <<"1) slash attack" << '\n';
            cout <<"2) punch" << '\n';
            cout <<"3) riposte" << '\n';
            cout <<"4) heal" << '\n';
            cout <<"5) block" << '\n';
            string input;
            cin >> input;
            switch (stoi(input))
            {
            case 1:
                cout << name << ": does a slash attack." << '\n';
                target.damage(10 , GameType::slash);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << name << ": punches " << target.getName() << " really hard"<< '\n';
                target.damage(4 , GameType::bludgeon);
                block(2);
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << name << ": hits " << target.getName() << " and retracts, really fast"<< '\n';
                target.damage(7, GameType::thrust);
                block(5);
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << name << ": channels the light element"<< '\n';
                target.damage(7, GameType::thrust);
                heal(4, GameType::light);
                break;
            case 5:
                block(12);
            
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
};

int main(){

    GameEntity *opponent = new GameEntity("enemy", 20, 3, 4);
    Player *player = new Player("player", 40, 4, 4);

    player->prepareForCombat();
    opponent->prepareForCombat();

    int r = 0;
    while(!player->isDead() && !opponent->isDead()){
        player->chooseMove(*opponent, r);
        opponent->chooseMove(*player, r);
        r++;
    }
    if(!player->isDead()){
        cout << "you won!";
    }else{
        cout << "you lost!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not what you are asking about but you are trying to program C++ as if it was like Java (for example creating objects with `new`). Don't do that, you really need to unlearn a lot of your Java knowledge to program C++ effectively.

Comment: When this kind of question gets asked the usual explanation is that there are two copies of the objects in question, the one you change and the one that you (wrongly) think has reset. But you haven't posted anough code here for me to be sure (although I'd wager a large sum of money). And of course object copying is not something that happens in Java, so this is probably another example where your Java knowledge is leading you astray.

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#. In C++ it is not necessary to create every object using the `new` keyword. Doing so typically results in a very common problem called "Pointless Use Of Pointers", which often evolves into the kinds of problems being described here. There's nothing in the shown code that requires pointers. You will do yourself a huge favor if you forget everything you learned about Java while writing C++. C++ works in fundamentally different ways, and your problem is most likely because you expect objects in C++ to work like they do in Java. They don't.

Comment: Before writing any real program I would recommend referring to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Note that by calling `new` without `delete` you create a memory leak. In Java you have GC, in C++ RAII is the way to go if you need to do heap allocation (not needed in this case). Another major difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem

```
void chooseMove(GameEntity target, int round){
```

As suspected you are changing `target` which is a **copy** of the object you actually want to change. Just change your code to use a reference

```
void chooseMove(GameEntity& target, int round){
```

In Java all object variables are references automatically. This is not true in C++. Here is the first clue that learning C++ means unlearning Java.

And a free piece of advice, don't use `new` here, just

```
GameEntity opponent("enemy", 20, 3, 4);
Player player("player", 40, 4, 4);
```

(and consequent changes in the rest of `main`).